# Make svcutil.exe generate Properties with no Order attribute

Tags: c#, svcutil.exe

I use `svcutil.exe` to generate proxy classes from a hosted WebService created by WebSphere that uses Java under the hood.

I am using the `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` and targeting Framework v3.5 with VS2010

The proxy classes are generated with the following attribute for each property

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=20)]
```

How can i tell the utility to **suppress generating the `Order`** parameter?